# Fullscreen resolution

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, performance

I want to squeeze more performance from my PC (Windows) when playing games and i want to know if lowering the resolution (+scaling to be the same size like the monitor 1080p) is better (performance wise) than lowering the resolution of the game but let it be a centered square in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I don't seem to understand what your question is... Why don't you give it a shot?

Comment: @Wingzero He's trying to deccrease the full-screen resolution (which is always, by default - The monitor size).

Comment: Yes yes I get it. I just don't get the "point" of asking. I think its preferably better to give it a shot first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a monitor (and graphics card) running at 1280x1024, for example, you will, on a particular video card, get a particular framerate. Lets say this is 30 fps for this example. If you reduce the resolution to 1024x768, your framerate will increase, because there are fewer pixels for the graphics hardware to render. Fewer pixels means it will complete a frame render faster, thus increased frame rate. If you continue to reduce your resolution (800x600, etc) your framerate will continue to increase. There are a couple of (hopefully obvious) caveats to this:

- Some games don't support all resolutions, and there is likely a minimum
- Some games are just not playable at lower resolutions, even if the game allows it, but this is pure preference
- Not all resolutions are the same aspect ratio (width to height ratio of your monitor) so your display may seem squashed flat, horizontally or vertically. (examples of aspect ratios are 4:3 (standard def) and 16:9 (widescreen))